# Arrayformula to add a generated code on specific rows

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula, array-formulas

I currently have this Google Sheet which consists of a dozen small tables listing people working on projects. Column A is currently empty, and I want to add an arrayformula in cell A2 which populates column A with a code. So in cells A2:A6 it should put a code which is generated from the department and project which will be "D41-P15". And when it reaches a cell in column B that contains "End" then it should leave the cell in column A blank. Then in cells A8:A18 it should put the department and project which will be "D29-P07". Etc. I need it to be an arrayformula so that if I want to add a person to a table I can just insert a row and the arrayformula automatically fills in the code in column A.

|  | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** |  |  |  |  |  |
| **2** | *=ARRAYFORMULA > D41-P15* | Dept | D41 | Project | P15 |
| **3** | *D41-P15* | # | First name | Last name |  |
| **4** | *D41-P15* | 1 | John | Smith |  |
| **5** | *D41-P15* | 2 | Joe | Bloggs |  |
| **6** | *D41-P15* | 3 | Sam | Jones |  |
| **7** |  | End |  |  |  |
| **8** | *D29-P07* | Dept | D29 | Project | P07 |
| **9** | *D29-P07* | # | First name | Last name |  |
| **10** | *D29-P07* | 1 | Tom | Cane |  |
| **11** | *D29-P07* | 2 | Sarah | Wilson |  |
| **12** | *D29-P07* | 3 | Emma | Mason |  |
| **13** | *D29-P07* | 3 | Javi | Garcia |  |
| **14** |  | End |  |  |  |

I've tried using this formula hoping that when it finds "Dept" in column B then it generates the code in column A, and when it finds "End" in column B then it leaves column A blank, otherwise it should copy the code from the cell above. But it only puts the generated code in A2 and A8. It doesn't copy the code generated in A2 in every cell down to A6, and doesn't copy the code in A8 down to A13. Any ideas how I can fix this?

`=ARRAYFORMULA( SWITCH( B2:B , "Dept" , C2:C&"-"&E2:E , "End" , "" , A1 ) )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good formula to do this kind of things is SCAN that lets you "remember" the last value.

Since it's scanning several columns, you can use SEQUENCE to refer to the rows and allowing you to use INDEX for each column.

```
=SCAN(,SEQUENCE(ROWS(A2:A)),LAMBDA(a,v, IF(INDEX(B2:B,v)="End","",IF(INDEX(B2:B,v)="Dept",INDEX(C2:C,v)&"-"&INDEX(E2:E,v),a))))
```

Comment: That works, thank you. How can I adapt this so that it only inserts the code if a first name is entered in column C?

Comment: Would it be in between a department?, If that's so, only SCAN won't work if the value to be "remembered" is some rows up. But you could use an ARRAYFORMULA to "empty" the values that result from SCAN when C column is blank: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(C2:C="","", SCAN(........)))` (Insert yourself the formula)

Comment: What I mean is that if I insert a new row below row 13 then the arrayformula would insert the code in cell A14. If I filter column A then it shows this blank row that doesn't have a person defined yet (in cells C14 and D14), and I'd rather it not show this line until a person is actually added. If you have an idea then that would be great, otherwise I'll just look into the SCAN function.

Comment: Have you tried the formula I suggested in the last comment?? I still understand that it would work for what you're looking for. The full version would be: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(C2:C="","", SCAN(,SEQUENCE(ROWS(A2:A)),LAMBDA(a,v, IF(INDEX(B2:B,v)="End","",IF(INDEX(B2:B,v)="Dept",INDEX(C2:C,v)&"-"&INDEX(E2:E,v),a))))))`